# How do I stop marking mail as read caused by looking at the preview pane?

Tags: mail.app, macos

I use Mountain Lion.

How do I prevent Mail.app (6.0) from marking a message as read automatically, just because I have looked at it in the preview pane?

Answer (score 5):

You can change the mark as read delay to a great value, for example 30 seconds, by typing the following in the Terminal:

```
defaults write com.apple.Mail MarkAsReadDelay 30
```

(NB: A value of -1 will disable marking as read from Preview if the preview window is hidden.  Tested on Mail 5.2/OSX 10.7.4)

Comment: Do you need to log out and log in again? I executed that in Mac OS X 10.8.4 but no effect. I doubt they removed the ability to do it even if it's not documented.

Comment: This don't work in Mavericks

Answer (score 3):

An other way to do do (without using the Terminal), is installing [TruePreview](http://christianserving.org/project/truepreview). It's an 3th party app which allows you to do exactly what you expect.

[image]

Do check for a recent version of TruePreview as older versions don't work well with Mountain lion.

Comment: The *defaults write* isn't being recognized by Mail.app in Mountain Lion. Recent versions of TruePreview weren't working either, but the latest build now works.

Comment: The latest release 1.8a4 supports ML - http://christianserving.org/project/truepreview/releases

Comment: I don't want to install that plugin though. What defaults write command will work in ML?

Comment: both links are now dead...